# Tangent and Normal question

Tags: calculus

> Which one of the following curve cuts the parabola $y^2=4ax$ at right angles?
>
> A) $x^2+y^2=a^2$
>
> B) $y=e^{-x/2a}$
>
> C) $y=ax$
>
> D) $x^2=4ay$

I think the answer is B and D (at $(0,0)$). But the book says only D.

Comment: The curve B) does not intersects the parabola at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The curve B) does not go through the point $(0,0)$ at all: it does go through $(0,1)$.

Comment: (0,0) is for D only, for B I did not find the point of intersection as it was unnecessary and complicated.

Comment: How could the point of intersection for B be unnecessary when you need to know if the angle of intersection *at that point* is a right angle?

Comment: I took log on both the sides (for B) and differentiated. I supposed that the point of intersection is (x1,y1) and found product of slopes for (B) and the parabola . Resulted (-1), therefore perpendicular(but though I'm not cent percent sure). Also I am sure that the curves meet by drawing rough graph.

Comment: My question remains that whether B is one of the answers or not.

Answer (score 0):

D is the reflection of the parabola in the line $y=x$, and has horizontal gradient at the origin, while the original curve has vertical gradient at the origin. So the answer is D.

Comment: Is B not an answer

Comment: Have you tried sketching a graph?